# How to build my own Jetty distribution

Tags: maven, jetty

I need to build my own Jetty distribution, with customized xml and jar files. I use a pom.xml from the website: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/8.1.9.v20130131/.

I build my target use mvn install. In the resulting jar files, all Java code are compiled to .class, but there is no start.jar, start.ini, etc, lib directories. What did I do wrong? What is the correct procedure to do it?

Comment: Have a look at the maven assembly plugin - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/ and how for example jenkins and sonar are building their distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because jetty-all contains only the compiled class files.

What you probably want to build instead is the whole jetty and then get your distribution from jetty-distribution/target/.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Simply get the sources from: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/
Then from the root directory run "mvn clean install" and if it runs successfully, you'll have a jetty distribution in srcroot/jetty-distribution/target.
If that worked well, then modify whatever you need to modify, run the build again and have your customized distribution.